# What does Threads_connected=-1 signify in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I was running the following: `mysqladmin -u root -p ext -ri 10 | grep Threads_connected` and was kind of surprised to find that Threads_connected could be **-1**:

```
| Threads_connected                 | 1            |
| Threads_connected                 | -1           |
| Threads_connected                 | 1            |
| Threads_connected                 | -1           |
```

What does the -1 signify?

This is on MySQL 5.0.77 on x86_64.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps you are seeing [diff since last snapshot](http://mysqldatabaseadministration.blogspot.com/2007/05/negative-number-of-threads-connected.html)

Answer (score 1):

Because you have -r for relative specified in mysqladmin, the -1 indicates that someone disconnected since the last sample.  If you want to see the absolute values, remove -r.